# Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'std::string *' (aka 'basic_string<char> *')

Tags: c++, scanf

I am writing a C++ program, where I need to read some formatted lines from a file in C++, which is in the format:

```
<N>
<x> blah blah blah <y>
<x1> blah blah blah <y1>
<x2> blah blah blah <y2>
```

where x and y are strings. I wrote this code to scan it:

```
fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fin, "%s blah blah blah %s\n", &data::x, &data::y) != 1) break;
        pairs.push_back({(string) data::x, data::y});
}
```

where `N` is an integer, `data` is a namespace with strings `x` and `y`, and `pairs` is a `vector<vector<string>`. Even though `scanf()` and similar do not throw read errors, CLion gives me a warning:

> Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'std::string *' (aka 'basic_string *')

I tried changing `data::x` and `data::y` to `char *`, but then CLion gives me another warning:

> Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **'

When I run the program, nothing outputs to either standard output or the file.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

namespace data {
    string x, y;
}

int main() {
    int N;
    FILE *fin = fopen("foo", "r");
    ofstream fout ("bar");
    vector<vector<string>> pairs;

    fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fin, "%s blah blah blah %s\n", &data::x, &data::y) != 1) break;
        pairs.push_back({(string) data::x, data::y});
    }
    cout << pairs.size();
    for (vector<string> i : pairs) {
        cout << i[0] << ' ' << i[1] << endl;
    }

    fclose(fin); fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a more C++-style way to do it, or is there something that needs to be changed with my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more C++-style way to do it

Yes. The C++ style of input is to use `std::ifstream` instead of `std::fscanf`.

> But how do I use the formatting like I used for fscanf using ifstream?

You extract from the stream into a string to read a word, which is similar to using `%s`, except you can read into `std::string` as well as any other type that supports it.

There is no analogous functionality of skipping expected input like `scanf` has. You can implement it using following algorithm:

Peek at the next character. If it matches the expected, then extract it and move on to the next character. Otherwise extraction has failed. If there is no next character to expect, then extraction succeeded, and you can proceed to extracting `data::y`.

For complex use cases, I recommend a more structured approach such as a parser generator than ad-hoc implementation.

Comment: But how do I use the formatting like I used for fscanf using ifstream?

Answer (score 0):

`%s` expects a `char*` pointer to a buffer to write into, not a `std::string`. So you can fix the error by using an intermediate `char[]`, eg:

```cpp
fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &N);
char tempx[256];
char tempy[256];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (fscanf(fin, "%255s blah blah blah %255s\n", tempx, tempy) != 2)
        break;
    data::x = tempx;
    data::y = tempy;
    pairs.push_back({data::x, data::y});
}
```